# Create multidimensional array in for loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, multidimensional-array

I want to create a multidimensional array like this:

```
array[0][1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
array[1][21,22,23,24,25,26,27....]
array[.][....]
```

How can I do this in Javascript?

I have tried this:

```
var squares = new Array();
        for(var i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
        {
            for(var j = 1; j <= 20; j++)
            {
                squares.push(i, j);     
            }

        }
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Updated with the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var squares = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
{
    squares[i] = new Array();
    for(var j = (i * 20) + 1; j <= 20 * i + 20; j++)
        if (squares[i] == null)
            squares[i] = j;
        else
            squares[i].push(j);
}
```

Output comes like:

```
array[0][1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
array[1][21,22,23,24,25,26,27....]
```

Comment: I have already test that, and I get this error: Error: squares[i] is undefined

Comment: @user500468 Check now! :)

Comment: @user500468 Check the udpated answer. Was my mistake. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Use modulus operand to limit the inner array's size

```
var limit = 80
var inner_limit = 20
var square=[]
var inner =[]
for(var i=1;i<=limit;i++){
    inner.push(i)        
    if(i%inner_limit==0){
        square.push(inner)
        inner = []
    }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't give the expected output! :(

Comment: fix it, can you try again?

Comment: Good. Works now... Too complicated anyways! `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar: This example works better than yours. In your example, array[1] contains 11, 12, 13 etcetc..

Comment: @user500468 how can I make mine better, as this is slightly complicated. Yea, and that's what you wanted right? Oops, is it so, I will fix it right away..

Comment: @user500468 I have updated my answer to fix the faulty code! Sorry about that! `:(`

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = []; // Main array
var numArrays = 10, // Number of sub-arrays
    numPerArray = 20; // Number of squares per sub-array

for(var i = 0; i < numArrays; i++){
    var subArray = [];
    // Number to start at
    var start = i * numPerArray;
    // Count up to start + numPerArray
    for(var j = start; j < start + numPerArray; j++){
        subArray.push(j);
    }
    // Add to main array
    array.push(subArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with two "for" loops. In the first loop you go through the main array and for each element add the elements from the second loop.

```
var arrayLength = 10; // Main array length
var limit = 20; // Number of squares
var array = [];

for ( var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++ )
{
    array[i] = []; // Create subArray

    for( var j = 1; j <= limit; j++ )
    {
        array[i].push(j);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to add some sort of explanation about what your answer does/is, some context.